# How to delete document from firestore in recycler view in android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

How to delete a document from Firestore in recyclerView in android.

I have auto-generated documents id's I Want to delete that auto-generated id's data

I tried this but this is not working

```
private void removeData() {
     ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
     dialog.setCancelable(false);
     dialog.setMessage("Deleting this item...");
     dialog.show();

    CollectionReference colRef firestore.collection("topic");
    String id = colRef.document().getId();

    colRef.document(id).delete().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(PracticeActivity.this, "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PracticeActivity.this, "Unable to delete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Firebase", "onComplete: Error Unable to delete : " + task.getException());
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    });

}
```

**I got the success msg but when I see the database it is not deleted.**

and If you know how to delete the document then you can post your answer according to you.

**Edited!**

[image]

#### How Can I also delete that Image that is stored in my Firebase Storage if I delete that document.

because if I am able to delete that document then what can I do with that Image so I want to delete that Image from my Firebase Storage database both how can I do that?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and please also indicate the exact document you want to delete.

Comment: You're welcome, but I cannot see the requested screenshot.

Comment: I Edited question now you can see @AlexMamo

Comment: please read my question again I added some extra doubts @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
String id = colRef.document().getId();
```

It means that you are generating a new document ID. When it comes to a delete operation you should specify the existing document ID inside a `document()` call:

```
colRef.document(id).delete().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

If you don't store that ID anywhere, then you should consider storing it as a property of the document.

Comment: Yeah, I got thank you.  but how can I also delete that image that is stored in my firebase storage database

Comment: In the same way, you delete a document from Firestore. Create a reference that points to the exact image, by specifying all elements and then simply delete it.

Comment: Yeah why not @Alex Mamo

Comment: Please update your answer `.delete` have no parameters. Because for future visitors, they can confuse.

Comment: Right, my bad. Just updated my answer. Thank you for that.

Comment: thank you for the correction @Alex Mamo